# Sort 2 ActiveRecord arrays depending on :user_id and then merge into 1

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, merge

I am trying to build a "friending" function between users in my Rails app.
When a user makes a friend request, a new "Friend" Item is created:

```
@friend = Friend.create(:user_id => session[:user_id], :friend_id => params[:friend_id], :status => "pending")
```

The other user (:friend_id) can then accept or decline the request. On accept the status is changed to "accepted" and all of that works fine.

I'm trying to return a list of friends now but the problem that I have is that the Friend item can either hold the friends id in :user_id or :friend_id depending on who initiated the request.

I am returning all Friend items that have the logged in user id in either :user_id or :friend_id but i'm having trouble sorting these into 1 list of users that are not the currently logged in user (i.e users that are friends of the logged in user) once I have those Friend items. This is what I have so far, hopefully it will give you an idea of what I am trying to do.

```
@stalked = Friend.where(:user_id => session[:user_id], :status => "accepted")
# @stalked_friends = Users where id == :friend_id in @stalked list
@stalkers = Friend.where(:friend_id => session[:user_id], :status => "accepted")
# @stalker_friends = Users where id == :user_id in @stalkers list
@friends = @stalked_friends + @stalker_friends
```

I hope this makes sense and thanks in advance

Comment: Are you expecting the final `friends` to be an array of `User` or `Friend` object? Also check out my answer please.

Comment: If you instead created two records per friendship, one in "each direction", then this would be a simple matter of a "User has_many Friends through UserFriends" association.

Comment: @DavidAldridge I was wondering whether that would be better but i'm pretty new to this and thought that creating two records would be classed as repeating myself? Thanks for the tip though - would have certainly been easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this on a small set of data and it worked fine, it *should* work!

```
cuid = session[:user_id]
query = %Q{SELECT DISTINCT users.*
FROM users,friends 
WHERE (friends.user_id = #{cuid} OR friends.friend_id = #{cuid}) 
AND (friends.user_id = users.id OR friends.friend_id = users.id)
AND (friends.status = 'accepted')
AND (users.id != #{cuid})
}

@friends = User.find_by_sql(query)
```

Comment: You are retrieving Users instead of Friend objects

Comment: @MrYoshiji That's what he want,s check the demonstration at the end of the question and you'll notice that.

Comment: @TamerShlash that works.. thanks.. what exactly is this doing? Am I right in thinking it is taking ALL user that are referenced in the relevent friend tables and then excluding the users that match the cuid? (I have a lot to learn - i know)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
@friends = Friend.where("#{Friend.table_name}.id <> ?", session[:user_id])
                 .where(status: 'accepted')
                 .where("#{Friend.table_name}.user_id = :id OR #{Friend.table_name}.friend_id = :id", id: session[:user_id])
```

This `@friends` is still an ActiveRecord::Relation object, so you can do scope-chaining after that, add more where clause, add an order strategy, etc.

```
@friends = [logic before]

# reorder the friends list by id
@friends = @friends.order(:id)
# limit the friends list to 20 max
@friends = @friends.limit(20)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I think I might have been a little unclear in the question. I did actually want Users.. effectively all users that are mentioned in the friend join apart from the currently logged in user (i didn't think of it that way until i saw Tamers answer). still i didn't know that you could chain together multiple Wheres like that. Thanks for the tip.